# date with different style for day and month

Tags: html, css

In a table (datatable.js), in each cell of the first column, I need to display a date with this format: '15 Jan', '15 Feb', etc...

The number of the day has one style, and the month has a diferent style.

I "solved" it by 2 divs:

```
<div class="day-style">15</div>
<div class="month-style">Feb</div>

.day-style {
    font-weight: 25px;
    color: red;
}
.month-style {
    font-weight:16px;
    color: blue;
}
```

It looks like what I need, but, of course it is not a date format, so I can't sort it by date.

Is it posible to do what I need keeping the date format? 
I was looking for a while and I didn't found anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your date in `data-attribute`, and use it when sorting table.

```
<td data-date='15 Feb'>
    <div class="day-style">15</div>
    <div class="month-style">Feb</div>
</td>
```

Or you can use [unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) date format which is more convenient to handle:

```
<td data-date='1423947600000'>
    <div class="day-style">15</div>
    <div class="month-style">Feb</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a little simple javascript:

```
<time>15 feb</time>
```

you could add this JS:

```
$('time').each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    me.html( me.text().replace(/(^\w+)/,'<span>$1</span>') );
});
```

and just example styling would be (in sass):

```
time {
  color: red;
  span {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

This will make the `time` element look like:

`<time><span>15</span> feb</time>`

You can see a working example here:
http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/wGpGZJ